# Append a string as suffix to columns in data frame as the values from a column of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, append

I have a data frame as following,

```
data0 = pd.DataFrame({'PE03': ['CTA15', 'CTA15', 'AC007', 'AC007', 'AC007'], 
'AL01': [22, 22, 2, 2, 2], 
'AL02':['12', '13', '14', '15', '16'], 
'AL03' : [2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
 'PL03' :[3,7,8,9,1]})
```

`data0`

```
    AL01  AL02  AL03  PE03   PL03
0   22    12    2     CTA15  3
1   22    13    2     CTA15  7
2   2     14    3     AC007  8
3   2     15    3     AC007  9
4   2     16    3     AC007  1
```

And another data farme as,

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'main': ['CTA15', 'CTA15', 'AC007', 'AC007', 'AC007'], 
'sub': ['LUD1', 'KLM1', 'SAP1', 'SAP2', 'SOS'], 
'samples':['PE03', 'AL01', 'AL02', 'AL03', 'PL03']})
```

`data1`

```
   main   samples  sub
0  CTA15  PE03     LUD1
1  CTA15  AL01     KLM1
2  AC007  AL02     SAP1
3  AC007  AL03     SAP2
4  AC007  PL03     SOS
```

And what I wanted is to look for the matching columns from `data0` into `data1` in column samples and then append the values from sub to columns in `data0`.

The final output should look like this,

`data_2`

```
   AL01_KLM1  AL02_SAP1  AL03_SAP2  PE03_LUD1  PL03_SOS
0  22         12         2          CTA15      3
1  22         13         2          CTA15      7
2  2          14         3          AC007      8
3  2          15         3          AC007      9
4  2          16         3          AC007      1
```

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Read here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the tables to create the concatenated column names and reshape:

```
df1 = data0.T.merge(data1, left_index=True, right_on='samples')
df1 = df1.assign(colname=df1['samples']+'_'+df1['sub'])
data_2 = df1.set_index('colname').T.drop(data1.columns).rename_axis(None,1))
```

Output:

```
  AL01_KLM1 AL02_SAP1 AL03_SAP2 PE03_LUD1 PL03_SOS
0        22        12         2     CTA15        3
1        22        13         2     CTA15        7
2         2        14         3     AC007        8
3         2        15         3     AC007        9
4         2        16         3     AC007        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
 sub = data1.set_index('samples').loc[data0.columns]['sub']
 data0.columns = [x + '_' + y for x, y in zip(data0.columns, sub)]
```

It just finds the matching `sub` value for each `sample` and appends it to the column name in `data0`.